# numpy: circular definition in source code

Tags: python, numpy, circular-reference

I went to look up the source to [np.transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) ( [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L495) ) and the definition seems circular?

```
def transpose(a, axes=None):

    try:
        transpose = a.transpose
    except AttributeError:
        return _wrapit(a, 'transpose', axes)
    return transpose(axes)
```

If all `transpose(a)` does is call `a.transpose` then how do we look up `a.transpose`?

---

What part of the code is doing the transposition?  All I see is referral to another transpose function.

Answer (score 3):

It's not actually a circular reference. `a.transpose` is a reference to the object's method, not the function defined by numpy. It's effectively saying "If object `a` already has a `transpose` method, then leave it alone; otherwise, use `_wrapit` to wrap the object `a` in an `ndarray` object".

As the `ndarray` class has a `transpose` method, forcing the Python object into that class gives the object access to the method.

This is a little outside my area of expertise, but it would appear that `ndarray` is defined in the C portion of the numpy code, so that would be where you'd find the actual logic behind it.

Comment: so there are other `transpose` methods floating around numpy, depending on the type of my object?

Comment: @johnmangual, seems like ```_wrapit``` is meant to handle all others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for `_wrapit`:

```
File:       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py
Definition: numpy.core.fromnumeric._wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
Source:
def _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
    try:
        wrap = obj.__array_wrap__
    except AttributeError:
        wrap = None
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
    if wrap:
        if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):
            result = asarray(result)
        result = wrap(result)
    return result
```